# Verify my answer on induction definition for the set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Write an induction definition for the set A={<a>, <b,a,b>,<a,b,a,b,a>,
<b,a,b,a,b,a,b>,….}

basic: < a > ∈A

induction:if bxb∈A then a::bxb::a ∈A

if a::x then b::x::b ∈A

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your notation.  What is $x$?  What does :: mean?

Comment: IT means cons()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition seems to work, roughly. Your use of $x$ and $::$ seems a bit inconsistent though. Here’s another way of writing it that is a bit more precise.

**Basis:**

$\langle a \rangle \in A$

**Inductive step:**

$\langle a::x \rangle \in A \implies \langle b::a::x::b \rangle \in A$

$\langle b::x \rangle \in A \implies \langle a::b::x::a \rangle \in A$

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Feel free to explain the tree induction!thx !

Comment: @toby I’ll give it a try.